# Django - Make query based on information provided from a user on front end. Not all filters will be used every time. How to achieve this?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a problem. I am building an app which user can select some filtering options in a form. Not all options will be used each time. I don't know how to build proper Django query.

At first I tried this approach:

```
if mileage:
    if mileage_less_more == 'mileage_less_than':
        cars = cars.objects.filter(price__lte=mileage)
    if mileage_less_more == 'mileage_more_than':
        cars = cars.objects.filter(price__gte=mileage)

if production_year:
    if production_year_less_more == 'production_year_less_than':
        cars = cars.objects.filter(production_year__lte=production_year)
    if production_year_less_more == 'production_year_more_than':
        cars = cars.objects.filter(production_year__gte=production_year)
    if production_year_less_more == 'production_year_exact':
        cars = cars.objects.filter(production_year=production_year)
```

I assumed that it would work like any other variable in python and even if one of the above filters won't be used (mileage will be None for example) then it just won't execute.
But this kind of approach is not supported by Django as I learned.

Then I tried many weird things with f strings but it also didn't work.

Then I tried with this approach:

```
if mileage:
    if mileage_less_more == 'mileage_less_than':
        mileage_qs = Car.objects.filter(price__lte=mileage)
    if mileage_less_more == 'mileage_more_than':
        mileage_qs = Car.objects.filter(price__gte=mileage)
else:
    mileage_qs = Car.objects.all()

if production_year:
    if production_year_less_more == 'production_year_less_than':
        production_year_qs = Car.objects.filter(production_year__lte=production_year)
    if production_year_less_more == 'production_year_more_than':
        production_year_qs = Car.objects.filter(production_year__gte=production_year)
    if production_year_less_more == 'production_year_exact':
        production_year_qs = Car.objects.filter(production_year=production_year)
else:
    production_year_qs = Car.objects.all()

cars_final = Car.objects.all().intersection( mileage_qs, production_year_qs)
```

And it works. but it will cause problems later. I need to do more filtering on this `cars_final` item. And Django also doesn't support filtering after intersection.

I could try later in my code just paste whole `cars_final` and before `intersection()` apply additional `filter()` but it will get really messy really fast.

I am sure that there is more elegant way to do it but I just don't know how and I am not able to google it. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/. It has everything you need in terms of filtering and it is easy to setup. Trying to create your own filters is more complicated than one might think.

If you really want to create you own filters, you can use keyword arguments to build your query dictionary before passing it to your queryset. Something like this:

```
data = {}

if variable == 1:
    data['key'] = 'foo'
elif variable == 2:
    data['key_2'] = 'bar'

if data:
    MyModel.objects.filter(**data)
else:
    MyModel.objects.all()
```